# How to train network in tensorflow with different number of samples in input and output?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement the Diet network (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09340.pdf) in TensorFlow. To give you a brief about the network, the Diet network tries to predict the weights of the input layer of the main network by using an auxiliary network, and I am trying to train both networks simultaneously. The input of the auxiliary network does not depend on the number of samples of the main network. Thus, both the input may have different numbers of samples. In my implementation, the number of samples in the auxiliary layer will always be  1.

```py
class BinryMSECustom(keras.losses.Loss):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred):
        
        bn = binary_crossentropy(y_true[0], y_pred[0])
        ms = mse(y_true[1], y_pred[1])
        return bn + ms

input1 = keras.Input(shape=(n_features,), name='classification_input_NxNd')
input2 = keras.Input(shape=(n_features,), name='auxilary_input_NdxN')

#Common
emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=n_features, output_dim=extracted_features_count, 
                        embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(pca_data),
                        trainable=False, name='feature_Embedding_NdxNf')(input2)

#Aux network as encoder
aux_enc_mlp = layers.Dense(100, activation='tanh', name='aux1_mlp_NdxNh1')(emb)

#Aux network as decoder
aux_dec_mlp = layers.Dense(100, activation='tanh', name='aux2_mlp_NdxNh1')(emb)

#Classifier network
x = layers.Dot(axes=1)([input1, aux_enc_mlp]) #Insert aux encoder
x_branch = layers.Dense(hidden_layer_1, activation='relu', name='classification_mlp_1_Nh1xNh2')(x)
x = layers.Dense(hidden_layer_2, activation='relu', name='classification_mlp_2_Nh2x1')(x_branch)
clf_out = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='Output')(x)

decode_branch = layers.Dot(axes=-1)([aux_dec_mlp, x_branch])

model = keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=[clf_out, decode_branch])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=BinryMSECustom(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
```

Training data :

```py
np.random.seed(0)

n_samples = 200 #N
n_features = 10000 #Nd

data = np.random.random((n_samples, n_features))
labels = np.random.permutation([0]*50+[1]*50)
pca_data = skde.PCA(n_components=0.95).fit_transform(data.T)

extracted_features_count = pca_data.shape[1] #Nf
hidden_layer_1 = 100 #Nh1
hidden_layer_2 = 50 #Nh2
```

The training step looks like this:

```py
emb_inp = np.array(list(range(0, n_features))).reshape(1, -1)
model.fit(x=(data, emb_inp), y=(labels, data), epochs=1)
```

When I call the above command for training, I get the below error:

```py
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 200, 1
  y sizes: 200, 200
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

One possible solution could be to repeat the second input `200` times (for this example). **But I am curious to know why TensorFlow has such a check and what could be the potential solution without changing the input?**

Answer (score 0):

@princethewinner, I could suggest two possible solutions for the problem. First, we'll have a look at the architecture of the your model (made with `tf.keras.utils.plot_model`),

[image]

Assuming that `N` is the number of samples, equal to `10000` in this case, the shapes of inputs and the outputs are,

```
# Shape of input tensors
(200, N )
(1, N )

# Shape of output tensors
(100,)
(200, N )
```

Clearly, the number of samples are not equal ( `200` vs `1` ). The second input, that has a shape of `( 1 , N )`, meaning that this tensor would remain a constant input for all `200` samples of the first input, of shape `( 200 , N )`. Moreover, the `feature_Embedding_NdxNf` layer is also set to `trainable=False` making its outputs constant for any given inputs.

> If you observe, you'll realize that the output of the `feature_Embedding_NdxNf` is constant for all `200` samples because of constant `( 1 , N )` input and `trainable=False` nature.

1. As you've mentioned in the question, the appropriate solution to the the problem would be to repeat the constant vector `( 1 , N )` `200` times so that the shape becomes `( 200 , N )` hence resolving the ambiguity around the number of samples. This shouldn't affect the model, as a constant embedding output is provided to aux1_mlp_NdxNh1`and`aux2_mlp_NdxNh1`.
2. You can pre-compute the output of `feature_Embedding_NdxNf` as it remains constant for all `200` samples. By doing so, you will get `emb_output = Embedding( ... )( input2 )` of shape `( 1 , N , 187 )`. Repeat the tensor along axis 0, for 200 times, to get a tensor of shape `( 200 , N , 187 )` and feed this tensor as input to your model in `model.fit( ... )`. This solution inherits from the 1st solution, the difference being that we're eliminating layers from the model which would always deal with constant inputs.